# use aetest.NewContext in place of endpoints.NewContext for testing go-endpoints with strong consistency

Tags: unit-testing, google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-endpoints

I have a search method:

```
func (sa *SearchApi) Search(c endpoints.Context, r *SearchQuery) (*SearchResults, error) { .. }
```

as you can see it takes an endpoints.Context e.g:

```
ctx := endpoints.NewContext(req1)
```

however with aetest, i'm using different context:

```
otherCtx, err := aetest.NewContext(&aetest.Options{"", true})
```

Particularly this context has extra options for strong consistency - since i'm setting up data so I can test a read only api.

I can't pass the otherCxt through to my Search method because it's not an endpoints.Context

otherCtx:

```
type Context interface {
    appengine.Context

    // Login causes the context to act as the given user.
    Login(*user.User)
    // Logout causes the context to act as a logged-out user.
    Logout()
    // Close kills the child api_server.py process,
    // releasing its resources.
    io.Closer
}
```

endpoints.Context:

```
type Context interface {
    appengine.Context

    // HTTPRequest returns the request associated with this context.
    HTTPRequest() *http.Request

    // Namespace returns a replacement context that operates within the given namespace.
    Namespace(name string) (Context, error)

    // CurrentOAuthClientID returns a clientID associated with the scope.
    CurrentOAuthClientID(scope string) (string, error)

    // CurrentOAuthUser returns a user of this request for the given scope.
    // It caches OAuth info at the first call for future invocations.
    //
    // Returns an error if data for this scope is not available.
    CurrentOAuthUser(scope string) (*user.User, error)
}
```

what's the recommend approach for testing go-endpoints with aetest? Is it possible to just transform the aetest context into the endpoints context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
inst := aetest.NewInstance(&aetest.Options{StronglyConsistentDatastore: true})
r, _ := inst.NewRequest("GET", "/", nil)
c := endpoints.NewContext(r)

sa.Search(c, ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

as per what alex said I have the following solution:

```
func TestApi(t *testing.T) {
    inst, _ := aetest.NewInstance(&aetest.Options{StronglyConsistentDatastore: true})
    defer inst.Close()
    r, _ := inst.NewRequest("GET", "/", nil)
    c := endpoints.NewContext(r)
    makeCourses(c)
    api := SearchApi{}
    searchQuery := &SearchQuery{"my-search-term", nil}
    searchResults, _ := api.Search(c, searchQuery)
    log.Println("got results %v", searchResults)
}
```